# What is a good definition of a mathematical structure?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, model-theory, foundations

At the moment I am writing a textbook in Foundations of Mathematics for students and trying to give a precise definition of a mathematical structure, which is the principal notion of structuralist approach to mathematics, formed by Bourbaki. Intuitively (and on many examples) the notion of a mathematical structure is clear: this is a pair $(X,S)$ consisting of a set $X$, endowed with a structure $S$, which is a set somehow related to $X$. This relation of $S$ to $X$ is well-defined in universal algebras or first-order theories. What about the general case?

I arrived to the following definition and would like to ask some terminological questions.

The main idea is that a mathematical structure is determined by a list $\mathcal A$ of axioms. By an *axiom* I understand a formula $\varphi(x,s,c_1,\dots,c_n)$ in the language of Set Theory with free variables $x,s$ and parameters which are some fixed sets $c_1,\dots,c_n$.

> **Definition.** A *mathematical structure* of type $\mathcal A$ is any ordered pair of sets $\langle X,S\rangle$ such that for any axiom $\varphi$ in the list $\mathcal A$, the formula $\varphi(X,S,c_1,\dots,c_n)$ is true.
>
> The set $X$ is called the *underlying set* of the mathematical structure $\langle X,S\rangle$ and the set $S$ is called its *structure*.

In the list $\mathcal A$ of axioms we can encode all desired properties of the structure $S$, for example that it is an indexed family of some operations or some relations on $X$ that have some desirable properties.

> The question is how to call the list of axioms $\mathcal A$ determining a type of a mathematical structure? Which properties of the list $\mathcal A$ guarantee that mathematical structures of type $\mathcal A$ form a category (for some natural notion of a morphism between mathematical stuctures of type $\mathcal A$)?

I have a strong feeling that such questions has been already studied (and some standard terminology has been elaborated), but cannot find (simple) answers browsing the Internet. I would appreciate any comments on these foundational questions.

Comment: Isn’t this just a specific kind of first-order two-sorted semantics?

Comment: But in this way higher-order properties can be encoded as well. For example, that $S$ is a subset of some $n$-th power-set of $X$. I assume that we can automatically use the axioms of set theory (for example, ZFC).

Comment: Right but nothing in the semantics forces $S$ to have some relation to the *real* powerset, right?

Comment: I understand a mathematical structure as a subset of the set-theoretic universe in which the real power-sets are well-defined. The formulas determining a mathematical structure are formulas of the language of Set Theory and use some fixed (for each formula) sets as parameters (but also can have no parameters at all). So, if necessary, I can use the true membership relation inside of the formulas. Then I obtain something related to the second-order logic.

Comment: What I want is to give a simple definition of a mathematical structure, which would include all examples of mathematical structures that arise in mathematical practice. I admit that the definition can be too general, but it should exist. Because it is not good to speak about mathematical structures as the main subject of study of mathematics (according to Bourbaki) and avoid providing a definition. If we accept the Set-Theoretic apprach, a unique undefined notion should be a set (or a class in NBG) and an element. Everything else should have a definition (desirably short and  understandable).

Comment: I often see Bourbaki's structures quoted, but it never includes the definition (e.g., the ["mathematical structure" Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) says essentially nothing about them— what they say suggest that the writer had little idea about what they are). I see little point in quoting them if one completely ignores their formalism, which is precisely defined.

Comment: @YCor By the way, what is the definition of a mathematical structure according to Bourbaki?

Comment: I once open the book at the right pages and it would take a while to read and understand, and I didn't so far. But it's your own question: quoting the "structuralist approach due to Bourbaki" let assume that you have an idea about what is it.

Comment: @YCor What is totally strange is that in French Wikipedia there is no page "Mathematical Structures" at all! But this should be the first language where this Bourbakist notion had to be explained! Moreover that there are whole books explaining the importance of mathematical structures of Bourbaki to the modern development of mathematics. Isn't it strange?

Comment: France or French Wikipedia has particular responsibility to advertise Bourbaki's foundations. I'm not sure what you mean with "whole books", but certainly I see no point in quoting work when one has no idea about what it is.

Comment: @YCor On one hand, every mathematician has a (I suspect vague) idea what is a mathematical structure via examples. The preceise definition is somewaht escaping as well as the precise definition of the subject of mathematics. What does it study? We should somehow to answer this question teaching students the couse in Foundations of Mathematics. After thinking a bit I arrived to the definition I suggested in my question: a mathematical structure is a pair of sets (or better classes) $(X,S)$ which are related somehow, i.e., via precisely defined formulas of Set Theory.

Comment: @YCor Concerning "whole books" I have just searched by Google and found some articles (not books, sorry): https://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/publications/articles/pdf/bourbaki-structures-synthese.pdf https://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/publications/articles/pdf/images-structures.pdf  But there is also a book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-7917-0

Comment: All I understood is that Bourbaki's structures include topological spaces (which I didn't expect), so it's much more general than just algebraic systems. The amount of arid formalism discouraged me to go seriously into it so far. I don't know if it's considered as interesting now, or if it has been completely superseded, and hopefully some people know more about this.

Comment: @YCor So, this is my question to know the opinion of experts. As I understand, the Category Theory somehow overshaded the notion of a mathematical structure since often mathematical structures of given type singnature (of how it is called?) form a category and then we can treat them individually without inventing any strange definitions.

Comment: Interesting paper by Leo Corry. But it's really a paper about the history of mathematics around Bourbaki, and not a paper about foundations and structures, which would give credit to Bourbaki. So I rather see it as considering (when it was written, namely 1992) Bourbaki's structures as important at a historical level.

Comment: @YCor The formal definition of a Bourbaki's mathematical structure  is described by Leo Corry on page 323 of his paper. Bourbaki had an aim to define a mathematical structure in a way that allows to define morphisms simultaneously, but I am not sure that this approach will give all possible mathematical structures because for example, the structure of power-set has two natural definitions of a morphism: using images or preimages. So, the mathematical structure $(X,P(X))$ has two different extensions to a category.

Comment: @YCor Having in mind the example of the structure $(X,P(X))$ (which are objects of two different categories), we can conclude that the connection between mathematical structures and Category Theory is not straitforward. Some mathematical structures form categories, some not, other form categories in many naturals ways. So, mathematical structures and categories are two different areas of mathematics with only a partial intersection. Mathematical structures are maninly related to the "object" part of categories. Right?

Comment: I can't say yes or no, not knowing precisely what a "mathematical structure" is. If I stick to algebraic systems, which is reasonably broad, but is at least a precise framework whose definition I understand [set endowed with a family of finitary relations and laws], I agree that they yield subcategories of the category of sets in sometimes several natural ways (even in basic cases such as totally ordered sets, or graphs).

Comment: Reading the thread, I made a bad typo and of course meant *"France or French Wikipedia has* **NO** *particular responsibility to advertise Bourbaki's foundations"* Having a look at the MathSciNet citations of the Set theory treaty by Bourbaki: there are quite few (10 times less than Lie, 4 times less than General topology), not particularly French-centered, and quite few seem to be related to structures (but I haven't looked into details).

Comment: Your highlighted question in the text seems different from the question title.  Are you asking what *would* be a good definition of "mathematical structure" that would form categories?  Or have you already settled on *your* proposed definition and are asking what properties of your axioms would ensure that you get a category?

Comment: @MikeShulman Initially I was asking about a precise definition of a mathematical structure but eventually I have found some reasonable answer myself and this answer is formulated in the question after some edit. Does this my definition agree with common understanding of a mathematical structure? I do not know. Mathematical structures in my understanding form a category whose morphisms are arbitrary  functions between the underlying sets.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h3068095

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I doubt that there is any generally accepted definition of "structured set" in mathematics that includes a notion of morphism and does not already use the technology of category theory.  (For a "behavioral" definition that does use category theory, see for instance [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property).)  As has been noted in the comments, very few mathematicians have even ever seen Bourbaki's actual definition, and it probably had some issues.

The definition you propose seems too broad.  Allowing arbitrary formulas of set theory enables axioms like "$x=\{\emptyset\}$", so you would have a type of structure such that $\{\emptyset\}$ admits that structure but $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ does not.  This is contrary to the general understanding of structuralism that a "structure" should be transportable across any bijection.

Probably the best-known general notion of "structured set" that forms a category (and is isomorphism-invariant) would be the models of a first-order theory.  One can expand the class of models here by considering infinitary languages.  However, this doesn't include examples such as topological spaces, which are still intuitively "structured sets".

The obvious way to remedy this difficulty is to use higher-order logic.  The problem is that there is no obvious "correct" way to define non-invertible morphisms between models of a higher-order theory.  How do you make continuous maps of topological spaces fall out of a general notion of morphism, given the contravariant character of continuity on open sets?

There are at least partial solutions to this problem, although I don't think any of them is standard or well-known.  For instance, the *double* powerset functor is covariantly functorial in a canonical way (induced from the contravariant functoriality of the single powerset), so if we restrict our higher-order signatures to contain only relations between elements of iterated powersets $P^n(x)$ where $n$ is even, then there is a straightforward definition of morphism of structures.  One can then represent and axiomatize topological spaces with such a signature having a single predicate on $P(P(x))$ that picks out the supersets of the topology, and the induced morphisms will be continuous maps.  (We discovered this as part of our work on the [higher structure identity principle](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.06572).)

It's less clear that this approach can also represent morphisms between structures that should be covariant on subsets, but it seems to to be possible in at least some cases, such as suplattices.  One could also try to augment a higher-order signature with explicit "variance information" that would determine the morphisms.  Unfortunately, it's hard to make (let alone prove) a general claim that any such approach "always works" without any existing general notion of "structure" (with attendant notion of morphism) to compare it to!

Defining *invertible* morphisms between structures, on the other hand, is entirely straightforward.  So if all you want is a *groupoid* of structures, then higher-order logic should do the job.  This is one of the arguments for the "more foundational" nature of groupoids over categories: the *groupoid* of topological spaces (for instance) is uniquely and canonically determined by the notion of "topological space" (expressed, for instance, as a higher-order theory), but the same can't really be said for the usual *category* of topological spaces (from a purely abstract point of view, what privileges continuous maps over, say, open maps?).

So if your goal is just to have a definition with which to "speak about mathematical structures as the main subject of study of mathematics", I would say that higher-order logic is probably the best answer.  If you also want to use this as a lead-in to introduce category theory, then my suggestion would probably be to discuss particular examples, then general morphisms of models of first-order theories, then *isomorphisms* of models of higher-order theories, then mention that defining a correct general notion of noninvertible morphism in terms of a higher-order theory is tricky, and finally *use* that difficulty as a motivation to refocus attention not on the notion of structure (i.e. the objects of the category) but on the entire category itself as an object of study.

Comment: Thank you for your answer from which I have learned many interesting things. My initial goal concerning mathematical structures was to give a desirably simple formal definition of a mathematical structure, which would include all know examples, confirming the known claim of Bourbaki that mathematical structures are main objects of study of mathematics. This definition had to be included into a textbook for undergraduates (that do not specialize in Logic of Set Theory). So, I eventually arrived to some solution, see the textbook at  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340899536

Answer (score 2):

My main comment is this: I would do it differently.

My training tends to look at (set-based) determinations of structures as an arrangement or system of sorts which is a (often finite) tuple of sets, and then separately a language which has a tuple of symbols and rules for what characterizes a well formed sentence, and then some correspondence which allows one to interpret or apply sentences to the tuple of sorts to see if indeed the sentence is true or holds in the system of sets.  Your initial attempt tries to rewrap these two notions into one, but I see that as causing problems later when you want to apply the sorts (or variations on them) to other languages (or variations on the first language): in your scheme you may have to throw out script A and rebuild from scratch script B in order to consider these changes.

This set based version will also not apply to those systems that emphasize a notion of relation over membership.  It's taking me a long time to learn to use category theory because I am loathe to give up the habits developed with using membership, and it is hard for me to switch to manipulating objects and arrows without trying to interpret them as domains and functions. Yet a lot of new programming languages and structures in computer science benefit from adopting different perspectives on structures, especially viewing objects by their properties and not by their (membership-based) constituents.

You might try a goal-oriented approach.  First determine what you want to do, and then try to organize structures to accomplish your goal.  If a lot of your work depends on establishing a form of equality or containment, then go with set based.  If much has to do with relations or elegant expression of procedures, consider a notation that captures the fundamental of the relational or procedural work you will do.

I recommend for inspiration George Bergman's invitation to universal constructions (his 245a class text of similar title), followed by chapter 3 of Algebras, Lattices,Varieties by McKenzie McNulty and Taylor, which has two formulations of category theory. Then try some books on Haskell or other functional programming language.  Hilbert and Ackermann's classic text on higher order logics, and Hans Hermes book on computation (title escapes me) consider other systems like Fitch's minimal calculus.  If your formulation(s) does not consider all of these for mathematical structures, I think you are setting the bar too low.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2020.05.21.

Comment: To address your question directly, the language part would be called an axiomatization or a theory.  In computer science or software development it might be called a specification.  I would call it a set of goals or requirements.  Gerhard "Different Strokes For Different Folks" Paseman, 2020.05.21.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I look at Bergman's book. It seems to be a more-or-less standard couse in Universal Algebra and this is the first examples that should be covered by a right definition of a mathematical structure. This indeed, can be covered by my approach: just form a list $\mathcal A$ of formulas saying that the mathematical structure $S$ is an indexed family of operations of a given signature and postulate their desirable properties (e.g. associativity commutativity, distibutivity etc). Everything like this can be easily done selecting specific formulas.

Comment: As I wrote in comments to comments of YCor, it seems that mathematical structures can (and should) be used only for definiting objects of suitable categories. Defining morphisms is a different task which is closure to Category Theory. A typical example is the mathematical structure $(X,P(X))$ containing a set $X$ and its power-set, this is the same as discrete topological spaces. This structure can be completed to a category in two ways: defining morphisms as images of preimages.

Comment: Indeed.  Bergman' text is used for Universal Algebra, but my training says Category Theory is a separate and not always compatible (with UA) theory. (I never took Bergman's 245 class formally.) Bergman's text impressed me as an attempt to use both disciplines to do mathematics in a more or less harmonious fashion.  Perhaps your formulation will strike me as even more harmonious.  Gerhard "Have A Good Theme Song" Paseman, 2020.05.21.

Comment: I ask you to consider the following possibility.  Don't settle on one formalism for structure.  It is like trying to write a programming language to handle all tasks. You can do it, but then optimizing to do some tasks more efficiently than others becomes awkward and cumbersome, and does not lead to quick understanding.  Instead, consider different formalisms and their relative advantages to one another.  You can even try to arrange them in a formalist hierarchy if needed.  Gerhard "That's How Mathematics Is Understood" Paseman, 2020.05.21.

Comment: In fact, my aim is not very ambitious: writing a textbook for student (not very deep), I want to mention that according to Bourbaki, the Mathematics studies mathematical structures, then give a general (but precise and correct) definition of a mathematical structure as a pair $(X,S)$ of a set $X$ and structure $S$ satisfying something (?? - that was my question), then give examples of some simple mathematical structures (semigroups, monoids, groups, rings, fields, graphs, orders, topological spaces), define their homomorphisms and switch smoothly to basic Category Theory.

Comment: By the way, the von Neumann-Bernays-Godel Set Theory (with classes) allows to give a precise set-theoretic definition of categories, functors, natural transformations, etc. The problem with set-theoretic foundations of Category Theory arised at the level of the category of functors between two non-small categories. Functors between such categories are classes which in NBG cannot be elements (or objects) of other classes.

Comment: I think for this text then, you want to use the phrases "list of requirements" and "mathematical theory", and then invent your own abbreviation for them.  In other contexts they will find the synonyms "axiomatization" and "basis".  Gerhard "Less Technical Is More Helpful" Paseman, 2020.05.21.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will write very simply: a mathematical structure is a pair of classes $(X,S)$ satisfying certain list of axioms $\mathcal A$ determining the type of a mathematical structure. By an axiom I understand a formula $\varphi(x,s,C_1,\dots,C_n)$ with free variables $x,s$ and parameters $C_1,\dots,C_n$ which are some fixed classes. I use the von Neumann-Bernays-Gedel Set Theory, so use classes, not sets. This allows me to include to the list of mathematical structures, the  Convey's surreal line $\mathbf{No}$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number

Comment: The Convey's surreal line $\mathbf{No}$ has the structure of an ordered field, i.e., is a pair of classes $(\mathbf{No},S)$ where the structure $S$ is a 5-tuple of classes $(+,\cdot,0,1,<)$ consisting of two binary operations, two constants and a partial order. All  (except of $0$ and $1$) are proper classes satisfying the axioms of an ordered fields. So, everything work even in such a strange "proper" context.

Comment: I offer proofreading services for not much more than a few cups of coffee.  Having some familiarity with structures, I may give you even more value.  Gerhard "Is Worth A Few Drinks" Paseman, 2020.05.21.

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposal of proofreading. Of course I would gladly drink a few cups of coffee with you at the earliest occasion (for example, you can visit my city Lviv at ScottishBook Fest: http://www.math.lviv.ua/SBF/). If the proofreading concerns the mentioned book, its unfinished  version (without structures and categories, but with the surreal line) is here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340899536_CLASSICAL_SET_THEORY_THEORY_OF_SETS_AND_CLASSES